# How can I change this line so i will download files with spaces in the name

Tags: php

I am trying to download a file(s) that will have spaces in the name. the script works fine for names without spaces but not if there is a space. I understand why this happens but not how to fix the issue. I have spent the better part of a day searching the web for a answer with out any luck so far.
So here is my question. How can I change this file to enable it to read the how name including the spaces.

```
echo"<a href=http://www.site.com/uploads/".$row['att'] ." download=".$row['att'].">Download attachment</a>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML attributes need quotes. Otherwise they are delimited by space.

```
echo "<a href=\"http://......../\">Download</a>";
```

Alternatively, you can correctly encode it as `%20`, but still, put quotes around your attributes...

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the attribute. Also, since it's going into html, it should be escaped.

```
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">Link</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what that "download" attribute is for, but you should look into [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) and [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
echo '<a href="http://www.site.com/uploads/'. urlencode($row['att']) .'" download="'.urlencode($row['att']).'">Download attachment</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers everyone working great now.
for reference here is what it looks like before and after.

Before

```
echo"<a href=http://www.site.com/uploads/".$row['att'] ." download=".$row['att'].">Download attachment</a>";
```

After

```
echo'<a href="http://www.sire.com/uploads/'.$row['att'] .'" download="'.$row['att'].'">Download attachment</a>"';
```

I had the quotes all mixed up and in the wrong places.